# Getting access to lineEdit in layout which is inside of another one

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I got a problem which I could not solve. I have a parent (added in QT designer) and child (added by code) layouts. I add `QLineEdit` and `Qlabel` widgets to child layout and then I add this layout to the parent one:

```
lbl = new QLabel(this);
currentResistorText += tr("Resistor") + tr("#") + QString::number(resistorCounter);
lbl->setText(currentResistorText);
newResistorLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
newResistorLayout->addWidget(lbl);
ui->resistorsLayout->addRow(newResistorLayout);
```

How can I get access to the `lineEdit` elements inside of `newResistorLayout`?
I'm using Qt 5.8.

Answer (score 0):

Look into these three functions:

```
QList<T> qFindChildren(const QObject *obj, const QString &name = QString());

QList<T> qFindChildren(const QObject *obj, const QRegExp &regExp)

T qFindChild(const QObject *obj, const QString &name = QString());
```

You can write code like this:

```
QList<QLineEdit *> edits = qFindChildren<QLineEdit *>(newResistorLayout);
```

Then you can loop through the edits and do what you like. Additionally, if the object has name that you know (set via `setObjectName`), you can specify the name to find **exactly** the one you are looking for.

**NOTE**: GUIs that you create via the designer will usually have names on all widgets, the uic tool will emit code to set all of the object names.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Did it like that: QList<QLineEdit *> widgets = ui->centralwidget->findChildren<QLineEdit *>();